# Probability set function of the random variable $X$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let a point be selected from the sample space $S = (0,10)$. Let $C \subset S$ and let the probability set function be: $$P(C) = \int_C \frac1{10}\ \mathsf dx$$ Define the random variable $X$ by: $$X(c) = 2c - 10.$$ Find the probability set function of $X$.
>
> Hint: if $-10 < a < b < 10$, then $$a < X(c) < b \iff \frac{a+10}2 < c < \frac{b+10}2.$$

I don't understand what should I do, and I don't know how the hint should help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the range of $X$ is $(-10,10)$.

By definition, the probability set function of $X$ satisfies:
$$P_X((a,b))=P(\{c| a<X(c)<b\})$$

Now can you understand the hint better?

Comment: yes I do. thanks.